# Binary search of sorted list that find the closest value in list to targeted value provided by the user Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, list, sorting, search, binary-search

can someone help me how to access all the float point values and do a binary search so that if one match it will output the title which is the second on in the list. For example, looking at the output below if 0.369 was matched it will output selfish.
Thank you.

so far the out put of the list is this [['0.369', 'selfish', 'Future'] ['0.412', 'family', 'Future']] the list is sorted based on the decimal value from lowest to largest it is all stored in storage = [ ]

Comment: Do you need to implement a binary search, or any other data structures that can be used? There are also other ways that exist without the binary search.

Comment: unfortunately, I have to use the binary search method.

Comment: if nothing else is there a way to access all the decimal numbers from the sorted list? I can try to figure out the binary part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you properly here is what you are looking for:

```
def binary_search(storage, target):
    first = 0
    last = len(storage) - 1
    while first <= last:
        mid = (first + last) // 2
        value = float(storage[mid][0])
        if target == value:
            return storage[mid][1]
        elif value < target:
            first = mid + 1
        else:
            last = mid - 1
    return -1


storage = [["0.369", "selfish", "Future"], ["0.412", "family", "Future"]]

target = float(input("Please enter the desired float "))

result = binary_search(storage, target)
print(result)
```

Please make sure you add data validation. For instance what happens if the user enters invalid value "abc"?

Comment: omg thank you so much you are actually a lifesaver thank you, sir and I will add a catch-all statement so invalid input can be avoided